# Watir::Element ole_object value when accessing object directly vs. using collection

Tags: ruby, watir, win32ole

Let's say I have a single link with a class 'example'. `a(class: 'example').ole_object` returns nil, whereas `as(class: 'example').first.ole_object` returns a WIN32OLE object. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that Watir::Element is lazily located, where as Watir::ElementCollections are located immediately.

The Watir::Element#ole_object method simply returns the value of `@o`:

```
def ole_object
  @o
end
```

`@o` is only set when the `locate` method is called:

```
def locate
  @o = @container.locator_for(TaggedElementLocator, @specifiers, self.class).locate
end
```

When you create a Watir::Element, but do not do anything with it, you can see that it is not yet located (ie lazy located):

```
p browser.link(id: 'an id that does not need to exist')
#~ #=> #<Watir::Link:0x..fc40fdd4a located=false specifiers={:tag_name=>["a"], :id=>"an id that does not need to exist"}>
```

Once the element gets located, typically when `locate` is called through another method such as `text`, the `@o` will get set with the Win32OLE object:

```
e = browser.link
p e.ole_object
#=> nil

e.locate # this is called internally by other methods such as text, click, etc.
p e.ole_object
#=> #<WIN32OLE:0x30de3c0>
```

In contrast, you will see that the element collection methods, such as `links` will immediately go and find all elements. As a result, those elements will already be located and have a `@o` specified.

```
p @browser.links(id: 'some id that exists')
#<Watir::LinkCollection:0x58b43284 length=1 container=#<Watir::Browser:0x40fa1c8c url="https://some.page.com" title="Test Page">>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've noticed this when I tried to pass the link to some function simulating a hardware click which required ole_object to exist.